# How to disable OneSignal notification popup?

Tags: android, onesignal

Is it possible to NOT show the popup notification of OneSignal and instead create one programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some research i found it out and is pretty straightforward.
here is the link to the offical doc on how to do it. 
[OneSignal Android Customizations](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding)

There are few step to achieve it:

1- Create a NotificationExtenderServiceClass

```
 public class NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample extends NotificationExtenderService {
     @Override
     protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
     // Read properties from result.

     // Return true to stop the notification from displaying.
     return true;
   }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty clear, turning read to true will stop showing notifications.
But what the docs doesn't says is that FCM will stop working and instead the notifications will pass here.

2 - add the service to Manifest

```
<service
   android:name=".NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

That's it.
Now, adding your logic inside NotificationExtender you will be able to freely manage your notifications.